# Passing Image to another ViewController from a tableViewcell (Xib file)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[screenShot of the tableView cell with 3 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSxUu.png)

i have used a xib file to generate a tableview cell.in tableViewcell class i am passing either 1/2/3/more images to show up the images like facebook. now when i tap on the imageView of the tableviewcell(it can be 1/2/3) i want it to show the picture in full screen.i've added tapguest recognizer in the image Views. But i am not able to pass the image to the second ViewController. any help ?

cellForRowAt indexpath code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.index =  indexPath.row

        cell.cellConfig(withText: text , withImage: (photo3 as? [UIImage]))
        cell.isExpanded = false

        let tapToNavigate =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDetailsPicture))
        let tapToNavigate2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDetailsPicture))
        let tapToNavigate3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDetailsPicture))


        tapToNavigate.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        cell.photoView1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.photoView2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.photoView3.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        cell.photoView1.addGestureRecognizer(tapToNavigate)
        cell.photoView2.addGestureRecognizer(tapToNavigate2)
        cell.photoView3.addGestureRecognizer(tapToNavigate3)


        return cell
    }
```

tapguest recognizer handler code :

```
    @objc func handleDetailsPicture() {

        let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsPictureViewController") as! DetailsPictureViewController
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

   }
```

cell class function code :

```
func cellConfig(withText text:String? , withImage Image: [UIImage]?) {


        self.seeMoreInPicture.isHidden = true

        photoView1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        photoView2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        photoView3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        photoView1.clipsToBounds = true
        photoView2.clipsToBounds = true
        photoView3.clipsToBounds = true


        if text == nil {
            self.textViewHeightCOnstrain.constant = 0
            self.bottomSpaceBetSeemoreAndContainer.constant = 0
            self.imageContainerViewHeight.constant = contentView.frame.height

        }

        if text != nil && isExpanded == false {

            let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

            if text!.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: width, font:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)) > 100 {
                self.textViewHeightCOnstrain.constant = 100
                self.seeMoreButton.isHidden = false
            }

            else if text!.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: width, font:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)) < 100 {
                self.textViewHeightCOnstrain.constant = text!.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: width, font:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14))
                self.seeMoreButton.isHidden = true
            }
            self.textView.text = text
        }


       self.textView.text = text

        if Image == nil {
            let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
            self.textViewHeightCOnstrain.constant = (text?.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: width, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)))!
            self.imageContainerViewHeight.constant = 0
            self.photoView2Height.constant = 0
            self.photoView3Height.constant = 0
            self.bottomSpaceBetSeemoreAndContainer.constant = 0
        }


        else if Image?.count == 1 {
            self.imageContainerView1Width.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
            self.trailingBetweenContainers.constant = 0
            self.photoView1.image = Image![0]

        }

        else if Image?.count == 2 {
            self.photoView3Height.constant = 0
            self.photoView2Height.constant = imageContainerViewHeight.constant
            self.photoView1.image = Image![0]
            self.photoView2.image = Image![1]

        }

        else if Image?.count == 3 {
            self.photoView1.image = Image![0]
            self.photoView2.image = Image![1]
            self.photoView3.image = Image![2]

        }

        else {
            self.photoView1.image = Image![0]
            self.photoView2.image = Image![1]
            self.photoView3.image = Image![2]

            self.seeMoreInPicture.isHidden = false

        }
    }
```

secondViewCOntroller Code :

```
class DetailsPictureViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailsImage: UIImageView!

    var imageToShow = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.detailsImage.image = imageToShow

    }
}
```

Comment: don't use tap gesture. Use table delegate method didSelectRow which gets called when you select/tap a cell.

Comment: need to add gesture as I'm already using the didselectRow method for the see more behavior of the textField.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're not passing any information to the secondVC

```
class DetailsPictureViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailsImage: UIImageView!

    var imageToShow = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.detailsImage.image = imageToShow

    }
}
```

this code does not set or tell anything  the app to do

```
self.detailsImage.image = imageToShow
```

tell the app what to do when prepareForSegue is ready and set the image

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "DetailsPictureViewController" {
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsPictureViewController
            destination.imageToShow = photoView1.image //example
        }
    }
```

then in your **secondViewCOntroller**

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailsImage: UIImageView!
var imageToShow : UIImage?
```

in viewDidLoad

```
postingImage.image = imageToShow
```